# How to free the GPU memory for texture when i do not need the texture?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a webVR application where i have to show the FPS. So, i have been using `Sprite` with `SpriteMaterial` to show the FPS.

For the every FPS change, i do the following -

1) Remove the current `Sprite`.

2) Create a texture with the new FPS (using `canvas`).

3) Create a new `Sprite` and set the created texture in the `SpriteMaterial`.

4) Add the `Sprite` in the scene.

Output is something like this -

[image]

My problem is, when i remove the previous texture, it does not free/invalidate the GPU memory it has taken for the texture. So, every time i create a new texture, GPU memory usage is ascending. Please check the following images -

**Initially -**

[image]

**After some time -** 
[image]

I have tried the following code, but it does not clear the GPU memory for the texture -

```
previous_sprite_mesh.material.map.dispose();
scene.remove(previous_sprite_mesh);
```

Can anyone please tell me, how should i clear the GPU memory for the texture used before? Also, any other approach to achieve what i am trying to do will be appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Three.js version - 77

Comment: Why would you need to create a new sprite and texture every time? Do you create a new SpriteMaterial every time too? You should just creating them once and redrawing the canvas

Comment: @2pha yes, that way the problem is solved.